# What do "Items of new constraints" and "All frames in container" mean?

Tags: ios, xcode

Under the "Update Frames" in the constraints section of the storyboard there are two options. The first one is "Items of new constraints", and the second one is "All frames in container" What do they mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two subviews and you add constraints for one, "items of new constraints" will update the frame of just the view to which you just added constraints and "all frames in container" will update the frames of all the subviews.

The former option is useful if you've a only supplied the unambiguous constraints for one subview but have not gotten to the constraints of the other subviews yet. On the other hand, if all of the constraints for all of the subviews have been completely defined, then you might go ahead an update all frames (esp if there are constraints in one subview that will affect the frame of others).

Obviously, if you haven't finished setting up the constraints for even the current subview, though, you might choose to not update any frames yet. If you tell it to update frames before you finished specifying the complete set of unambiguous constraints, you can get some surprising behavior (e.g. nonsensical frames), so the ability to specify whether to apply the constraints yet, and for which views, can be very useful.